# Why are Listeners in Java interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, listener

Why are all Listeners in Java interfaces? Why can't they exhibit their behavior as classes?

Comment: Why **shouldn't** they be interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't allow multi-inheritance, so all classes have exactly one direct superclass. If listeners were classes, you would not be able to extend any other class at the same time. But listeners don't have any fields, and they only provide methods for the subclass to override, so they can be interfaces as well. This means you can yourself extend another class if you need to, and it allows you to implement multiple listeners in one class.

So, essentially, it is almost always better to declare classes that you want to override and that don't have fields as interfaces instead of abstract classes. With Java 8 you can even declare `default` methods, so the methods don't even have to be abstract.